# How to calculate the inverse Laplace transform of $F(s)=\frac{1}{1-e^{-s}}$?

Tags: laplace-transform

How to calculate the inverse Laplace transform of this function?

$$F(s)=\frac{1}{1-e^{-s}}$$

Comment: what is the inverse Laplace transform of $e^{-a s}, a \in \mathbb{R}$ ? and if you assume the domain of convergence of your Laplace transform is $Re(s) > 0$, then you can use $\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k$ whenever $|z| < 1$

Comment: It's Dirac function $\delta (t-a)$ . Could you please have more comments?

Comment: that's all, expand $F(s)$ as I said and inverse Laplace transform each term, you'll get a nice distribution

Comment: $\delta(t)+\delta(t-a)+...$

Comment: that's unclear   (and once you have the distribution, it is obvious that its Laplace transform is $F(s)$ assuming $Re(s) > 0$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(\mathcal{L}^{-1}F)(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\mathcal{L}^{-1}(e^{-ns})=\sum_{n\geq 0}\delta(x-n) $$
is a one-sided [Dirac comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb).

Comment: nice， if this one-sided sample a decay signal $e^{-t}$， what is the sampled signal Fourier transform?

Comment: The downvote is for?

Comment: Sorry newbie here.

Comment: @MikeMeng: Probably you accidentally downvoted my answer (and accepted it, too, that is quite uncommon), but to reply to your previous question, you just have to compute $$\sum_{n\geq 0}e^{-n}$$ that is a geometric series.

Comment: @MikeMeng the signal is $y(t) = e^{-t} 1_{t > -\epsilon}$, the sampled signal is $y_n = e^{-n} 1_{n \ge 0}$, and its (discrete time) Fourier transform is $Y(\omega) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty y_n e^{-i \omega  n} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n}e^{-i \omega  n} = F(1+i\omega)$. So that the Fourier transform of $y(t) 1_{t > -\epsilon}$ sampled at every integer is the Fourier transform (in the sense of distributions)  of $y(t) \sum_{n=0}^\infty \delta(t-n)$

Comment: Thanks all. the Fourier Transform from different methods  is different. $$\mathcal{F}(e^{-t} 1_{t > -\epsilon})=\frac{1}{j\omega+1}$$ $$\mathcal{F}(\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta (t-n))=2\pi\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(\omega-2n\pi)$$ multiplication is equivalent to the frequency convolution.  $$\mathcal{F}(e^{-t} 1_{t > -\epsilon}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta (t-n))=\frac{1}{2\pi} \mathcal{F}(e^{-t} 1_{t > -\epsilon})*\mathcal{F}(\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta (t-n))=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+j\omega+2\pi n}$$ This is different from $F(1+i\omega)$.